# GeoServer times out (504 Gateway Time-Out) when accessed from OpenLayers via nginx webserver

Tags: nginx, openlayers, geoserver, http-status-code-504

I have developed an OpenLayers web app that uses GeoServer.  I am using nginx as my webserver with proxy_pass setup for GeoServer.  Everything works as expected when I use "localhost" but when I switch to my IP address I get a 504 Gateway Time-Out error for

```
http://98.153.141.207/geoserver/cite/wfs.
```

I can access GeoServer at

```
http://98.153.141.207/geoserver/web
```

via a browser without problem so it would appear the proxy continues to work as expected.

The GeoServer log shows this when the problem occurs:

```
Request: describeFeatureType
    service = WFS
    version = 1.1.0
    baseUrl = http://98.153.141.207:80/geoserver/
    typeName[0] = {http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite}MyLayer
    outputFormat = text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1
```

Then after a minute, I get the 504 Gateway Time-Out in my JavaScript console and this      shows up in the GeoServer log:

```
09 May 06:02:15 WARN [geotools.xml] - Error parsing: http://98.153.141.207/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?version=1.1.0&typename=cite:MyLayer
```

I have tried this supposed problem URL in a browser and it works fine.

The nginx erorr log contains this:

```
2013/05/09 06:02:15 [error] 420#3844: *54 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while reading response header from upstream, client: 98.153.141.207, server: localhost, request: "GET /geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?version=1.1.0&typename=cite:MyLayer HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?version=1.1.0&typename=cite:MyLayer", host: "98.153.141.207"
```

Further investigation reveals that this problem seems to be restrict to WFS layers only.  The WMS layers work fine.   Here is the declaration of my WFS layer that fails:

```
myLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("MyLayer",
                                    {
                                      strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(),saveStrategy],
                                      projection: "EPSG:2276",
                                      protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS(
                                      {
                                        version: "1.1.0",
                                        url: "http://" + hostip + "/geoserver/cite/wfs",
                                        featureNS: "http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite",
                                        srsName: "EPSG:2276",
                                        featureType: "MyLayer",
                                        geometryName: "Poly",
                                        schema: "http://" + hostip + "/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?version=1.1.0&typename=cite:MyLayer"
                                      })
                                    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

I managed to get this working by remove the "schema" property from the OpenLayer.Protocol.WFS of my layer.  Can anyone explain why this would be the problem?